# 414 Request-URI Too Large in Nginx

Tags: google-chrome, nginx

I have a site running on `192.168.9.51` with nginx.
**What happened:**
If I entered IP address `192.168.9.51` in the address bar. IP suddenly got multiplied and appended itself in the URL like this

```
http://192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/192.168.9.51/
```

Which results in `414 Request-URI Too Large in Nginx`
**Expected results:**
`192.168.9.51` should land me on the webpage without the above error.
What should I do to fix this error?
(I'm not sure whether its an nginx problem or a chrome problem)

Comment: Your configuration probably has a redirection statement (return or rewrite) and you have used `/` instead of `//` at the front.

Comment: thanks for the direction @RichardSmith , I'm not using `//`. My site is redirecting multiple times..